# Find new coordinates after rotating a shape centrally

Tags: matrices

i want to find new points of shape in Cartesian coordinate system after applying an angle on shape. What is formula to find these points

[image]

Comment: The rotation transformation can be expressed conveniently as matrix, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

The center of rotation is ( 50,-50) and angle through which you want to rotate each corner point of square is $45^0$ or $\pi/4 $ radians.

$ ( x_1,y_1) = (x,y) \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix} /\sqrt{2} $